# Design pattern for loading view in front-end JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am relatively new to web-programming and am looking for a simple pattern to show a "loading"/waiting view for the web. Before I say anything else, I am sending only the minimum amount of data from the server, and start sending the JS/HTML resources to client while the client is using AJAX to request more data from the server (this might be suboptimal but bear with me). So basically, in theory this should mean the web view pops up earlier initially, but spends more time loading some of the data and corresponding subviews. Thus the need for a loading view.

So we have the standard jQuery function .ready()

```
fetchSomeDataAsynchronously(); //self-explanatory

$(document).ready(function () {

    //should I load waiting view here or can I initialize it earlier??

    window.mainUserHomeView = new MainUserHomeView({el: $("#user-home-main-div")});
    window.mainUserHomeView.render();

    window.userHomeMainTableView = new UserHomeMainTableView({el: $("#user-home-main-table-div")});
    window.userHomeMainTableView.render();


     fetchTeamSnapTeams(); //fetch more data asynchronously

});
```

Maybe my question is simply - can I show a loading screen before .ready() fires and what does that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just include the script to show the view in your HTML's `head` or at the beginning of the `body`. Make sure that you put it after you've loaded your required resources (e.g. jQuery) though.

Simplified example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showLoadingView() {
                // ...
            }

            showLoadingView();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```